# ¿como guardar el valor de un input creado dinámicamente en la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, array

buenas tardes, espero puedan ayudarme, estoy haciendo un sistema de referido, la idea es que una sola persona (el referente) agregue campos dinámicamente y se aloje en la base de datos en campos separados como nombre, apellido, dni, teléfono del referido.
Resulta que tengo ese código, que lo saque de por acá.
Archivo

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>

<form action="2.php" method="GET">

    <div class="field_wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
    <input type="submit" name='Enviar' value="Enviar"/>
     </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

archivo 2.php que recibe los datos

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_GET['Enviar'])) {
        // recorremos el array
        foreach ($_GET['field_name'] as $key => $value) {
            echo 'La clave es '.$key.' y el valor es '.$value.'<br/>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, se genera los inputs pero recibo así:
La clave es 0 y el valor es nombre
La clave es 1 y el valor es apellido
La clave es 2 y el valor es dni
La clave es 3 y el valor es telefono

No se como insertar en la base de datos ya que estos campos tiene que ir en campos separados en la tabla del referente.

Muchas gracias de antemano, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Tienes que armar un SQL en forma dinámica. Comenta en tu posteo cómo es la estructura de la tabla sobre la que vas a insertar

Comment: Gracias Muc, ahi le dejo en el posteo la estructura de la base

Answer (score 0):

esa seria la estructura de la base
CREATE TABLE `referente` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`id_referido` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `referido`

CREATE TABLE `referido` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`apellido` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`dni` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`telefono` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`id_referente` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1